# Using HSlider: coercion of Event to SliderEvent

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, slider, flex4.5

Porting a pure Flash/AS3 application to Flex 4.5 this code:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.SliderEvent;
        import flash.filters.ColorMatrixFilter;

        private function handleSlider(event:SliderEvent):void { 
            var hide:Number = event.value;
            _settings.data.hide = hide;
            _settings.flush();

            if (hide >= 0.8) {
                filters = null;
            } else {
                var matrix:Array = new Array();
                matrix = matrix.concat([1, 0, 0, 0, 1]);    // red
                matrix = matrix.concat([0, 1, 0, 0, 1]);    // green
                matrix = matrix.concat([0, 0, 1, 0, 1]);    // blue
                matrix = matrix.concat([0, 0, 0, hide, 1]); // alpha

                filters = [ new ColorMatrixFilter(matrix) ];
            }
        }
     .......
        <s:HSlider id="_hide" right="8" bottom="30" width="80"
        minimum="0.25" maximum="1.00" value="1.00" stepSize="0.25"
        change="handleSlider(event)" />
```

gives me the error

```
Implicit coercion of a value with static type flash.events:Event 
    to a possibly unrelated type mx.events:SliderEvent.
```

How do I fix that? The Adobe [HSlider doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d95.html) is unusually sparse.

Is `mx.events.SliderEvent` still okay to use in a Flex 4.5 application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [change event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/TrackBase.html#event%3achangeEnd) is not a SliderEvent; it dispatches a generic event.  Just change the method signature for your event handler to remove the error.

```
    private function handleSlider(event:event):void {
```

You can access the value of the slider just by accessing the slider directly:

```
var hide:Number = slider.value;
```

Or possibly using the target of the event:

```
var hide:Number = (event.target as HSlider).value;
```

The [SliderEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/SliderEvent.html) you refer to is an MX Event; and I do not believe it is used in the Spark implementation.

You may benefit from reviewing the [ASDocs for the HSlider class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/HSlider.html).

Comment: Thanks, esp. for explaining how to get a hold of the value